# Bluetooth serial connection between Android and Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, bluetooth, connection, serial-communication

I'm working on an Android application and I have to make a Bluetooth serial communication between an Android device and a Computer with Ubuntu OS. I don't know what to do and how to connect them. I'm looking for good references and someone who can help me.

I made a button which navigates to the Bluetooth settings of our Android device. I don't know what else I should do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pair the devices. This has nothing to do with any software, so it has to be done via the phone settings
2. Once paired, look at 'Bluetooth Chat' example by Google. It has drop in code for connecting two devices. A serial connection is done via Serial Port Profile that is established over RFCOMM. The UUID for SPP is well known, again, you'll find it in the Bluetooth Chat example.